# Пастбище - это обстоятельство? «Пастух перегнал стадо на новое пастбище»

Tags: члены-предложения, дополнение, обстоятельство

> Пастух перегнал стало на новое пастбище.

Пастбище - это обстоятельство или дополнение?

Answer (score 1):

Это обстоятельство, отвечающее на вопрос "куда?" и обозначающее место действия.

Обстоятельство обозначает время, место, способ действия. Отвечает на вопросы: "где?" "когда?" куда?"
Дополнение обозначает предмет. Отвечает на вопросы косвенных падежей существительных "кого?" "чего?" "кому?"

Answer (score 0):

> Пастух перегнал стадо на новое пастбище.

Пастбище -- это обстоятельство. Если быть точнее, то даже обстоятельство места :))

Пастух прегнал стадо (куда?) на пастбище. Вопрос "куда?" -- вопрос обстоятельства места.

К дополнению задаются вопросы косвенных падежей. К слову "пастбище" в этом предложение нельзя задать ни одноого вопроса косвенного падежа.